# How to understand "as told" here?

Tags: conjunctions

> For believers, the Koran is a transcript of the word of God **as told** to
>   the Prophet Mohammed.

orginated from:[the article](http://www.okread.info/page/read.php?ys=1&d=201506&q=27159)

How to understand "as told" here?

What's the meaning of the whole sentence?

Comment: The word ... **as [*it was*] told** to the Prophet.  Verbatim.  The word = that which was said.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it up:

**as** in this sentence means 'the same way as'.

**told** is the past of *to tell*, which simply means that He spoke to the Prophet.

So, **as told** means 'the same way as he said it'.

So, the meaning of the whole sentence is as follows.

*The word of God* is a set phrase that means something like 'all rules and promises made by God', so basically what people believe God wants them to do, and what He will give them if they do so.

A *transcript* is writing something down literally, for example, you could make a transcript of a court hearing.

So, believers (people who believe in God, or in this specific case, Muslims) believe the following: God told the Prophet a lot of things about how He wanted people to behave. Someone then wrote down everything that was said, and that writing is the Koran.

Comment: Generally true and I've upvoted, but a couple of technicalities: 1. Tthe "word of" someone is not necessarily rules and promises, but anything they said. We talk about "the words of Shakespeare", meaning his plays and poems, not rules. People commonly say things like, "Have you heard any word from Uncle Bob?", usually asking for news, not commands. 2. "Believers" here means believers in Islam, not believers in God in general. Jews, Christians, and worshippers of Thor don't believe that the Koran is a transcription of the words of God.

Comment: 3. When we say "as told to", we usually mean that the person it was told to wrote it down, though I suppose not necessarily. But if he didn't write it down himself, then he must have in turn told it to someone else, so it's not "Al's story as told to Bob", but "Al's story as told to Bob who in turn told it to Cathy". Books listing a celebrity as the author often have a sub-heading "as told to ...", and then give the real author. The celebrity discovered he has no ability to write coherently but the publisher believes a book with his name on it would sell well. So he tells his story to ...

Comment: ... someone who's an actual writer, and then that person really writes the book. (Of course there are many reasons for telling your story to someone else to write it down, I'm not saying Allah isn't a competent writer!)

Comment: 1: I specifically refer to 'the word of God', which specifically refers to the (Islamic) doctrine. I'm not saying that's the only alternative meaning of 'the word of' - 'the words of Shakespeare' or 'any word from Bob' are completely different! 2: agreed. I tried to keep it general, but perhaps you're right I better keep it specific. 3: I'm not well versed in the Koran, but one could imagine Allah, Mohammed and John Doe sitting on a rock, with John recording the conversation between Allah and Mohammed. So, because I don't know how it's supposed to have happened, I said 'someone'.

Comment: Not to beat this to death, but RE #1, the Koran includes material other than rules and promises, such as historical narrative. RE #3, I should have separated that from 1 and 2, I wasn't saying that you were wrong there, just trying to say that the most common use of the phrase is, etc,

Comment: @Jay 1: I would like to call it 'doctrine', a word which meaning includes what narratives they believe in, but I figured that would be too difficult a word for the OP. 3: I had some trouble understanding what you actually meant there, but regardless, I don't know how it should change my answer - perhaps you could make a suggestion?

Comment: 1. "Doctrine" is plausible in the context of a religious text. Elsewhere I'd just say "whatever the person said".  3. Hey, I don't claim to have solutions. I just make gratuitous sniping attacks. Okay, seriously, I would have said something like "usually it's understood that the person hearing the message has written it down, though it could be relayed to a third party before being written", or something to that effect.